# Why does In/Out Toilet Flange Need Primer/Cement?

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a new toilet and noticed how terrible of a job the last contractor did on my last toilet install. I have patched the area where the pipe comes up thru the floor with cement. It is level with the tile floor now. The closet flange I bought goes into my 4" pipe and I have it anchored into the cement.

Do I really have to primer and glue the flange to the DWV pipe? It seems with the screws holding the flange in place, gravity will do the rest of the work as far as keeping leaks from happening.

[image: toilet flange]

Answer (score 2):

You need to glue it, you may not need to prime it.
The glue fuses the pipe together which not only prevents liquid leaks but also sewer gasses.

If you cemented it in without gluing it you need to chip your cement out, remove it, and install the flange properly using glue.

Comment: wow. didn't even think about the gasses. thank you ! btw, not sure if u noticed but the flange goes into the 4" pipe. So why would I need to chip out the cement in order to glue it?

Comment: If it's 4" cast iron, it was supposed to be a rubber grommet. If it's 4" PVC, that's the wrong flange size. - Take the screws out, it probably comes right off. And that's no good.